# Dynamically generating a react-bootstrap grid from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-bootstrap

I'm looking to dynamically generate a grid layout from the below object. I'm struggling to work the logic of this out.  For each row, I need it to generate the columns in it and within each column, I need spit out the widget. Note i am able to change the structure of the object if needed.

```
    const layout = {
      row: [{
        column: <Col sm={6} md={3} />,
        widget: <Temp />,
      },{
        column: <Col sm={6} md={3} />,
        widget: <Humidity />,
      },{
        column: <Col sm={6} md={3} />,
        widget: <Noise />,
      },{
        column: <Col sm={6} md={3} />,
        widget: <Lumanosity />,
      }],
      row:[{
        column: <Col md={12} />,
        widget: <Occupancy />,
      }],
  }
```

Example generated grid below:

```
        <Grid>

         <Row className="show-grid">

          <Col sm={6} md={3}>
            <Panel className="box">
              <Temp />
            </Panel>
          </Col>

          <Col sm={6} md={3}>
            <Panel className="box">
              <Humidity />
            </Panel>
          </Col>

          <Col sm={6} md={3}>
            <Panel className="box">
              <Noise />
            </Panel>
          </Col>

          <Col sm={6} md={3}>
            <Panel className="box">
                <Lumanosity />
              </Panel>
          </Col>

        </Row>

        <Row className="show-grid">
          <Col sm={12} md={12}>
            <Panel className="box">
              <Occupancy />
            </Panel>
          </Col>

        </Row>
      </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the constants within your code as shown below:

```
<Grid>

     <Row className="show-grid">

      <Col sm={6} md={3}>
        <Panel className="box">
          <toast />
        </Panel>
      </Col>

      <Col sm={6} md={3}>
        <Panel className="box">
          <cheese />
        </Panel>
      </Col>

      <Col sm={6} md={3}>
        <Panel className="box">
          <candles />
        </Panel>
      </Col>

      <Col sm={6} md={3}>
        <Panel className="box">
            <peppercornSauce />
          </Panel>
      </Col>

    </Row>
```

Comment: Explain why? An answer with just code doesn't help anyone!